# How can I simplify adding many of the same javascript files in my MVC3 Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC3 application I have many different screens and these all use a master layout. 
Seven of the screens all use the same code such as that below:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/x/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/y/ajaxOnFailure.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/y/tinyMCEOptions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/z/updateField.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/z/gridClick.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/z/createDialog.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/a/dialogSuccess.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/a/refreshGrid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to have some way of putting all of these lines into an external file and then have them added.

is there some way I can have one file which I add to my razor view and inside that file imports all the javascript files above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add them to a PartialView, then include the PartialView in the pages you want the scripts to show up on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this increase the time to handle each request. I guess time is needed to locate the partial view from disk and then do the import?

Comment: There is a performance hit, but it usually very negligible. Where you begin to see issues is when doing things like looping with PartialViews (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626272/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-slow). However, for how you want to use it, the performance hit should hardly be noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I use Combres very good script combiner and minifier its available on nuget.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new .cshtml file and impot all files inside that

```
/Views/Shared/Scripts.cshtml
```

and then add this to your view

```
@Html.Partial("Scripts")
```

Comment: Does this increase the time to handle each request. I guess time is needed to locate the partial view from disk and then do the import?

Answer (score 0):

Use a second layout that implements your master layout, but imports the scripts you need for your 7 views: A->B->views 1-7.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively check out the bundling and minification features which aims at simplification of these things and also will have your page load and render much much faster.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

This feature, by itself, is a good reason to move up to MVC 4.